# R: How to manipulate data ( Dataframe with NA values and an imputed matrix with multiple iteration results)?

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I have a data.Frame `df_final` with 2 columns:

`day_of_year` (365 sequential integers: 1,2,3,....365)

`bookings` (279 integer values and `86 NA` values for missing data)

here's a sample of `df_final`

```
     day_of_year  bookings
1       1           43
2       2           27
3       3           NA
4       4           27
.
.
10      10          NA
11      11          31
.
.
365     365         60
```

I have used the `Hmisc` package in R to impute the missing values with 5 iterations.

```
library (Hmisc)

impute_arg <- aregImpute(~ day_of_year + bookings, data = df_final, n.impute = 5)
impute_arg
bookings_imp_2 <- impute_arg$imputed$bookings
```

Please find a portion of the result of `bookings_imp_2`

[image]

[image]

[image]

There are 5 iterations for each missing value.

My goal is to take a `pooled version` of the imputed values (may be taking average of the 5 values) and replace the `NA values in df_final` with these values.

I have created the pooled data-set using

```
df_imputed <- data.frame("bookings_imputed" = bookings_imp_2)
df_imputed$pooled <- rowMeans(df_imputed, na.rm = TRUE)
```

I have an output like this

[image]

The only thing left to do is to replace the NA values in df_final with the pooled values. This is where I am a bit stuck.

Answer (score 1):

If the order of the rows are not changed this might work.

```
df_final$bookings[is.na(df_final$bookings)] <- df_imputed$pooled
```

Cheers, Rico